# How to create a python test suite?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am a novice in python.  I started learning it recently. I have scripts `a.py`, `b.py`, `c.py`, etc. Each contains a specific test case. I need a main script file which will execute `a.py`, `b.py`, `c.py`, etc, one by one. How should I do that?

Please help.

Comment: When you say 'one by one' does that mean that you need to execute them one at a time, or can you run all of them at once?

Comment: When you say each has a specific test case, do you mean a test case using the `unittest` module?

Comment: I wanted to create this for sanity test.So every test should run only once.As one script finishes another should trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
def execFiles(files):
    for file_name in files:
        exec(open(file_name).read())


>>> execFiles(["a.py", "b.py", "c.py"])
```

Comment: Thanks.Let me check this way.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.